# Slicing dates in python and sql

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a dataframe that has several columns and one of them is "account_closed_date". The data looks like:

| column_1 | column_2 | account_closed_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcde | 12345 | 2022-01-01 |
| fghij | 45544 |  |
| klmno | 12378 |  |
| asdff | 34564 | 2020-08-05 |
| ploif | 93458 | 2021-12-31 |
| asdhj | 01235 | 2021-10-20 |

Empty values in column "account_closed_date" mean that the account is still open.

I need to slice all values that came after 2021-10-31. To do that in python I'm doing the following:

```
df[~(df['account_closed_date'] >= '2021-11-01')]
```

However, when I try to do the same slicing in SQL I obtain a different result. The slicing that I'm doing in SQL is:

```
WHERE account_closed_date < CAST('2021-11-01' as DATE) OR account_closed_date IS NULL
```

How should I change my coding in SQL to obtain the same result?

Thank you very much
Regards

Comment: And what  result are you getting in python?

Comment: When I count the unique values of column_1 in SQL and Python I obtain different values. SQL values are almost 17% larger than in Python

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and sample expected output?

Comment: as for straightforward alternative - should not it be `where not account_closed_date >= CAST('2021-11-01' as DATE) `?

Comment: If I do "where not account_closed_date > CAST('2021-11-01' as DATE)", I obtain the same result as  WHERE account_closed_date < CAST('2021-11-01' as DATE). But I dont capture the data that is in the second part of the original where clause (account_closed_date IS NULL)

Comment: Yep, my bad. Still need the samples.

Comment: You should compare the rows that come out of Python and SQL to identify the difference. It will then give you a hint as to what is happening.